# Having a dependency on a specific nuget package

Tags: nuget

We have a bunch of internal packages that we create for other teams to consume, and many of these have dependencies on open sources packages. I would like to add a dependency to a specific version of a nuget package to my nuspec, such that when the end user installs my package the dependent packages get installed too.

My `<dependencies>` section of my nuspec looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="MassTransit" version="2.0.0.4" />
  <dependency id="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" version="2.0.0.4" />
</dependencies>
```

Which I was hoping would bring down only version 2.0.0.4 of MassTransit, however it brings down 2.0.0.5, which my application currently doesn't work with. I've tried the following formats, but none of them seem to work:

```
version="[2.0.0.4, 2.0.0.5)"
version="[2.0.0.4]"
version="2.0.0.5)"
```

Infact, I can't seem to get anything [in the documentation about version ranges](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/version-range-specification) to work properly.

I do have one thought, which is that masstransit is using a 4 digit version number, while all the examples are 3 digits a-la semver. Is this what could be causing my problem?

**Edit:**

It turns out the version of nuget on the build server was out of date and didn't support the ranges I wanted to use. Upgrading it fixed everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, doing something like [version] should get you the exact version.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work, it still pulls down 2.0.0.5 when you get the package.

Comment: I have this same problem. I have a project with reference to package Y version 1.2.0.0 When adding a reference to internal package x with reference on package y with version 1.2.0.0 the package Y with version 1.3.0.0 gets pulled into solution. 
WTF?

Comment: If you put [1.1.0.0] then it should work and never get anything but the exact version. If you have exact repro steps where this doesn't work file a bug with the exact package and repro steps.